# Identify a Star Wars fanfic in which Leia gave birth to Jabba's child

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, fan-fiction

I remember reading Star Wars fanfic. It was big (bigger than standard Star Wars books) and was written in a serious language (although I couldn't stop laughing). I was never able to finish it, but I can tell important points from the beginning:

- Leia gave birth to Jabba's child after the events of *Return of the Jedi*. It was explained in great detail how Hutts and Human cell/DNA mixing takes several years.
- There was also a photo of the child. Its body shape was that of a Hutt, but it had a head of a human and skin was smooth.
- Birth of the child also created a dispute between Han and Leia. Han even left Leia after that (BTW, I read it long before *The Force Awakens* was released).

Can you please identify this fanfic?

Comment: This is a perfectly well-written and answerable story id question which I'm sad to see downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for the nightmares of Jabba and Leia doing the hanky panky. Anyway, it seems... interesting, so you have my +1. If you remember any more details (year you read it etc), please add them.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - I downvoted because I don't want to condone this sort of deviancy

Comment: Instead of downvoting, I'll just say......ewww....

Comment: @Valorum Your votes are yours to spend as you see fit. That said, if I spent my votes the way you do I'd have to downvote every star wars prequel-related question on the site.

Comment: Aren't Hutts asexual?